# Pandas GroupBy list values in a column of lists and find their mean

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large pandas dataframe (1M rows) with the following format:

```
data = {
    'names': {0: ['Lily', 'Kerry', 'Mona'], 1: ['Kerry', 'Mona'], 2: ['Mona']},
    'sentiment': {0: 10, 1: 2, 2: 0}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

                 names  sentiment
0  [Lily, Kerry, Mona]         10
1        [Kerry, Mona]          2
2               [Mona]          0
```

I would like to compute the average sentiment for each unique name in the names column, resulting in the following:

```
   names  sentiment
0   Lily         10
1  Kerry          6
2   Mona          4
```

The number of unique names is extremely long so efficiency is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires an explosion on the "name" column first, followed by a standard `GroupBy.mean()`:

```
df.explode('names').groupby('names', as_index=False, sort=False).mean()

   names  sentiment
0   Lily         10
1  Kerry          6
2   Mona          4
```